# I am trying to print a boolean value in HLA program, but it shows a error . I dont understand where did I do wrong?

Tags: assembly, hla

I am learning assembly language from a book named "The book of Assembly language" by Randall Hyde. The author of this book uses a programming language called HLA.This language is designed by the books author.It has some high level language properties which aids in learning assembly language quickly.I was trying to print a boolean value with stdput.get() procedure. But it shows an error . I dont understand where did I do wrong. The program I have written is:

```
program booLean;
#include ("stdlib.hhf")
static
    BoolVars: boolean;
    HasClass: boolean := false;
    yoMan:   boolean  := true;

begin booLean;

stdout.put(HasClass);

end booLean;
```

And the error it outputs is:

```
Error in file "booLean.hla" at line 1 [errid:134802/hlaparse.c]:
syntax error, unexpected booleanTkn, expecting UndefID.
Near: << booLean >>

HLAPARSE assembly failed with 1 errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reserved words - such as `boolean` - [are case-insensitive in HLA](https://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/HighLevelAsm/HLADoc/HLARef/HLARef_html/HLAReference.htm#50401283_pgfId-999007). Therefore, you can't use `booLean`, `bOoLeAn` or any such variation as a program/procedure name. Just pick a different name.